# Probability: pick SIMULTANEOUSLY = pick ONE BY ONE?

Tags: probability

Of the 20 lightbulbs in a box, 2 are defective. An inspector will select 2 lightbulbs simultaneously and at random from the box. What is the probability that neither of the lightbulbs selected will be defective?

**My Attempt:**

- Pick Simultaneously: from 18 non-defective, I pick 2 simultanously
  $$18C_2 /20C_2 $$
- Pick individually:

(first pick non-defective)* (second pick non-defective)= (18/20)*(17/19)

---

The answer to the attempts above are the same. But I don't understand, am I suppoed to pick simultanously? I thought in my first approach, I **pick 2 at a time ( which is simultanously)**, but in my second approach, I **pick 1 by 1**. Why is the answer the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your confusion is more in "pick with replacement" and "pick without replacement." The "simultanously" is just meant to indicate "without replacement" -- which you are doing in both your attempts.

Comment: Simultaneously does it mean you pick 2 at a time?

Comment: How does it differ from picking 1 at a time? No difference at all?

Comment: Yes, at the same time.  From a sampling perspective, it's the same (you don't put them back, i.e. you don't have sampling with replacement). A *non* equivalent way would be with replacement: pick one lightbulb uniformly, look at it, put it back. Then pick another one (it could be the same lightbulb again!) uniformly, look a it. This would be *with* replacement.

Comment: You are right, that both considerations are equivalent. You can first assume, that you pick one by one . Then let the time between the two pickings go to zero ($t \to 0$). In this case you can take both ways of calculations.

Answer (score 1):

When I pick two fish from a barrel simultaneously, I then have two fish.

When I pick two fish from a barrel one at a time (without replacement), I then have two fish.

The probability that I have picked neither of the only two red herrings in the barrel of twenty fish is the same no matter which method I use.   How could it be otherwise?

It's not like the closer in time my right hand and left hand each grab a different fish will affect the probability of grabbing neither red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Here the order of choosing comes into play. In the sample space of your first attempt there is no order because of 'simultaneous' selection. But in sample space of second event (picking a defective bulb A followed by non-defective bulb B) and (picking B followed by A) are different outcomes (unlike in your first attempt). The answer coming out same is because both sample space and set of favourable outcomes are multiplied by 2 so ratio is unchanged.